# Correct gender version of Sanskrit name तेजस्वी or tejasvī

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, name

Not sure if this is a relevant question for this site.

**Is Tejasvi, a masculine or feminine term or name in Sanskrit?**

Any references from Hindu scripture or Sanskrit literature on how this word is used?

Some websites say that Tejasvi is neutral, while, Tejasvee or Tejasvī (with a long I) is masculine and Tejasvini is feminine.

Any Sanskrit experts here who can answer the above question?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! I made some edits to make your question generic as personal-advice questions are off-topic here. Please see this post on meta: [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/296/2995).

Comment: Tejasvee is masculine and Tejasvini is feminine - I would post an answer but not sure if Sanskrt grammar rules are allowed as answers on this site.

Comment: @Surya I think you should post.. I think its better if there is answer even for closed question..

Comment: @Surya Isn't tejasvī an adjective also? i.e., neutral?

Comment: @Krishnapriya. Please register. Continue visiting this site and post Q&A on this site in future too.

Comment: @sv There is no neutral adjective in Sanskrit - all adjectives takes the gender of the noun that is described. Eg. Tejasvi Ramah, Tejasvini Sita.

Comment: @Surya I think Sanskrit Grammar rules must be valid. Without Sanskrit and its Grammar, there is no Sanatana Dharma. But we can use them for our scriptures but not sure about names.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is Tejasvī, a masculine or feminine term or name in Sanskrit?

We see Tejasvī (with a long I) [being used](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm) as a name for Indra in the Mahābhārata:

> 01,189.028   vyāsa uvāca 
> 01,189.028a    etac chrutvā vajrapāṇir vacas tu; devaśreṣṭhaṃ punar evedam āha 
> 01,189.028c   vīryeṇāhaṃ puruṣaṃ kāryahetor; dadyām eṣāṃ pañcamaṃ matprasūtam

> 01,189.028d*1916_01     viśvabhug ṛtadhāmā ca śibir indraḥ pratāpavān 
>
> 01,189.028d*1916_02     śāntiś caturthas teṣāṃ vai **tejasvī** pañcamaḥ smṛtaḥ
>
> Vyasa continued, 'Hearing these words of the former Indras, the wielder of the thunderbolt once more addressed that foremost of gods, saying, 'Instead of going myself, I shall, with a portion of my energy, create from myself a person for the accomplishment of the task (thou assignest) to form the fifth among these!' Vishwabhuk, Bhutadhaman, Sivi of great energy, Santi the fourth, and **Tejaswin**, these it is said were the five Indras of old.

Tejasvī is also [used as](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/20378/13F_Chapter_8.pdf) an adjective for a female child:

> कन्यामरगर्भाभां ज्वलन्तीमिव च श्रिया । तां ददर्श समुत्सृष्टां नदीतीरे महानृषिः ॥८॥ 
> स्यूलकेशः स **तेजस्वी** विजने बन्धुवर्जिताम् । स तां दृष्ट्रा तदा कन्यां स्थूलकेशो महाद्विजः ॥९॥
>
> 01,008.007c   kanyām amaragarbhābhāṃ jvalantīm iva ca śriyā 
> 01,008.008a   tāṃ dadarśa samutsṛṣṭāṃ nadītīre mahān ṛṣiḥ 
> 01,008.008c   sthūlakeśaḥ sa **tejasvī** vijane bandhuvarjitām 
> 01,008.009a   sa tāṃ dṛṣṭvā tadā kanyāṃ sthūlakeśo dvijottamaḥ
>
> The great Rishi saw the girl lying forsaken in a lonely place on the banks of the river, **blazing in beauty**; she was as beautiful as a child of an immortal. And the great Brahmana,
> Sthulakesha, the chief of Munis, finding that female child.